# Can I reverse an applied radial blur?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I applied a radial blur of size 10 to an image and have since realised it looks awful. Is there any way I can reverse the radial blur effect I applied in photoshop?

Comment: Did you apply the effect with a Smart Filter or just as a regular filter on a layer? If you didn't use a Smart Filter, you're probably not going to be able to undo it (unless you made a copy of the original layer before you applied the filter). Check out: http://blogs.adobe.com/jkost/2012/02/ps-non-destructive-filters.html for more information about Smart Filters.

Comment: If you're still in the same session (haven't closed Photoshop) and you haven't made many more changes CTRL/CMD + SHIFT + Z (undo)! If not, use it next time.

Comment: It is possible, if you can make the inverse convolution kernel. In Photoshops tool-set this is impossible, but not with say Mathematica. Its another thing entirely whether you'd want to waste time on this. Even tough the problem is pretty easy to fix.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not, though it's difficult to say without seeing the image.

Hind-sight is 20/20, but you could have set the image as a **Smart Object** before applying the blur. This would have caused the blur to be applied as a [**Smart Filter**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WS5DBBE4BC-1BCD-4edf-A4D5-EAD30AC794A8.html), which is non-destructive and reversible.

[image: Radial blur Smart Filter]

Comment: Ah no I didn't. Thanks for the tip though, I'll keep that in mind next time!

Comment: @BenjaminFranklin or you can simply duplicate the layer and keep the 'spare' hidden whenever you are doing anything that is undoable.